# Problems with openlayers 5.3 and heatmap-layer (tiles look defect)

Tags: openlayers, heatmap, openlayers-5

I have some problems with a heatmap-layer in OpenLayers5.3.0.
When I zoom deeply in my application I need some very high 
blur- and radius-values:

```js
if (zoom==14){
   heatmap.setBlur(60);
   heatmap.setRadius(parseInt(160));
}
```

..therefore the tile then looks a bit weird:
[image: broken tile-image]

I wonder: Is there a possibility to change the tile-size at a heatmap-layer or much better: is it possible to create a heatmap-layer in a single tile?
Thank you very much, Kalle